.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd Rebuild Failed
When I first run npm run start after npm install I get an error
Error: The module '\\?\D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 115. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 119. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).

Then I try to run .\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
And this error appears
.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd
- Building module: canvas, Completed: 0
  Copying C:/libjpeg-turbo64/bin/jpeg62.dll to D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\
          1 file(s) copied.
  Backend.cc
D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(700,39): warning C4996: 'v8::Isolate::IdleNotificationDeadline': Use MemoryPressureNotification() to influence the GC schedule. [D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
  (kompilowanie pliku źródłowego „../src/backend/Backend.cc”)

D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2560,8): error C2665: „v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor”: żadna przeciążona funkcja nie może przekonwertować wszystkich typów argumentów [D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
  (kompilowanie pliku źródłowego „../src/backend/Backend.cc”)
      C:\Users\heink\.electron-gyp\28.3.3\include\node\v8-template.h(816,8):
      może to być „void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Name>,v8::AccessorNameGetterCallback,v8::AccessorNameSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)”
          D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2560,8):
          „void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Name>,v8::AccessorNameGetterCallback,v8::AccessorNameSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)”: nie można dokonać konwersji argumentu 5 z „v8::PropertyAttribute” do „v8::AccessControl”
              D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2568,7):
              Konwersja na typ wyliczeniowy wymaga jawnego rzutowania (static_cast, rzutowania w stylu języka C lub rzutowania w stylu funkcji ujętego w nawiasach)
      C:\Users\heink\.electron-gyp\28.3.3\include\node\v8-template.h(809,8):
      lub       "void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::String>,v8::AccessorGetterCallback,v8::AccessorSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)"
          D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2560,8):
          „void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::String>,v8::AccessorGetterCallback,v8::AccessorSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)”: nie można dokonać konwersji argumentu 2 z „Nan::imp::NativeGetter” do „v8::AccessorGetterCallback”
              D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2562,7):
              Ta konwersja wymaga operatora reinterpret_cast, rzutowania w stylu języka C lub rzutowania w stylu funkcji ujętego w nawiasach
      D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2560,8):
      podczas próby dopasowania listy argumentów "(v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::imp::NativeGetter, Nan::imp::NativeSetter, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::PropertyAttribute)"

D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2608,8): error C2665: „v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor”: żadna przeciążona funkcja nie może przekonwertować wszystkich typów argumentów [D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
  (kompilowanie pliku źródłowego „../src/backend/Backend.cc”)
      C:\Users\heink\.electron-gyp\28.3.3\include\node\v8-template.h(816,8):
      może to być „void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Name>,v8::AccessorNameGetterCallback,v8::AccessorNameSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)”
          D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2608,8):
          „void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Name>,v8::AccessorNameGetterCallback,v8::AccessorNameSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)”: nie można dokonać konwersji argumentu 5 z „v8::PropertyAttribute” do „v8::AccessControl”
              D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2616,7):
              Konwersja na typ wyliczeniowy wymaga jawnego rzutowania (static_cast, rzutowania w stylu języka C lub rzutowania w stylu funkcji ujętego w nawiasach)
      C:\Users\heink\.electron-gyp\28.3.3\include\node\v8-template.h(809,8):
      lub       "void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::String>,v8::AccessorGetterCallback,v8::AccessorSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)"
          D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2608,8):
          „void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::String>,v8::AccessorGetterCallback,v8::AccessorSetterCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,v8::AccessControl,v8::PropertyAttribute,v8::SideEffectType,v8::SideEffectType)”: nie można dokonać konwersji argumentu 2 z „Nan::imp::NativeGetter” do „v8::AccessorGetterCallback”
              D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2610,7):
              Ta konwersja wymaga operatora reinterpret_cast, rzutowania w stylu języka C lub rzutowania w stylu funkcji ujętego w nawiasach
      D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\nan\nan.h(2608,8):
      podczas próby dopasowania listy argumentów "(v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::imp::NativeGetter, Nan::imp::NativeSetter, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::PropertyAttribute)"

Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:203:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)

× Rebuild Failed

An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
node-gyp failed to rebuild 'D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\canvas'

Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\canvas'
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\RoboOptim\RoboOptim\node_modules\@electron\rebuild\lib\module-type\node-gyp\node-gyp.js:118:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)

I followed these steps -> https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation:-Windows
but with no result
The system is windows 11 Pro 23H2
